# Jquery getting more than one variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a small script that runs a php file in the background and gets a variable every 3 seconds and put it in a div

script in document with div

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#statmoney').load('safe.php');
            }, 3000);
        });
    </script>
```

PHP FILE (safe.php)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
$money = htmlspecialchars($row->money);

echo $money;
```

If i need to add another variable i would need to make a new document is there a easy way to go about it?

UPDATE

menu.php

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         setInterval(function () {

             var fields = ['money', 'ore', 'energy']; // array of needed fields

             $.ajax({        
                type: "POST",
                url: "menusafe.php",
                data: {'fields': fields},
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function(response) {

                   // assuming that we already have divs for respective fields
                   fields.forEach(function(v){

                       console.log(response)
                      $("#" + v).html(response[v]);
                   });        
                }
             });
         }, 3000);
     });
 </script>

<div class="menustats"><img src="graphics/logos/moneylogo.png" class="menustatimage"><div class="menustattext" id='money'></div></div>
<div class="menustats"><img src="graphics/logos/energylogo.png" class="menustatimage"><div class="menustattext" id="energy"></div></div>
<div class="menustats"><img src="graphics/logos/orelogo.png" class="menustatimage"><div class="menustattext" id='ore'></div></div>
```

PHP(menusafe.php)

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['fields']) && !empty($_POST['fields']) && is_array($_POST['fields']) ){
    $fields = $_POST['fields'];
    $fields = (count($fields) > 1)? implode(',', $fields) : $fields;
    $sql = "SELECT $fields FROM users WHERE id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
    $result = [];
    foreach($fields as $field){
        $result[$field] = $row->{$field};
    }
    echo json_encode($result);

}
?>
```

Comment: of course, you can locate all needed variables in one file

Comment: You should not be using `mysql_*` anymore as it is officially deprecated. Consider using `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statements.

Comment: @user1899614, Why have you make such conclusion: "set interval not refreshing"?

Comment: What are you asking here?  Are you asking how you return more than one variable via safe.php?

Comment: *"If i need to add another variable"* - being what exactly; what is it exactly that you wish to do?

Comment: yeh my appologies the title was from earlier i am asking how to get more than one varaible say if i wanted to put them in different divs using the jquery script how would i get them and seperate them

Comment: Please prefer prepared statements over inserting variables into the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine that we want to retrieve three fields from `users` table : `firstname`, `age` and `money`. In such case it would be better to use `$.post` or `$.ajax` method:
*js part:*

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         setInterval(function () {
             var fields = ['firstname', 'age', 'money']; // array of needed fields
             $.ajax({        
                type: "POST",
                url: "safe.php",
                data: {'fields': fields},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                   // assuming that we already have divs for respective fields
                   fields.forEach(function(v){
                      $("#" + v).html(response[v]);
                   });        
                }
             });
         }, 3000);
     });
 </script>
```

*php part: (safe.php)*

```
if ( isset($_POST['fields']) && !empty($_POST['fields']) && is_array($_POST['fields']) ){
    $fields = $_POST['fields'];
    $fields = (count($fields) > 1)? implode(',', $fields) : $fields;
    $sql = "SELECT $fields FROM users WHERE id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
    $result = [];
    foreach($fields as $field){
        $result[$field] = $row->{$field};
    }
    echo json_encode($result);

}
```

Comment: there are syntax errors on the php part on the firsth and third row but cant work out what they are?

Comment: @user1899614, I apologize, I've fixed it, check again

Comment: this doesnt appear to be doing anything if i update the database it does not refresh on the page without me refreshing it

Comment: make sure that there is strict conformity between element names and table field names. Check your table, check if everything conforms

Comment: Yes the element Id's are exactly the same as the rows

Comment: if problem still appears, show me `var_dump($sql);` of $sql varible from `safe.php`

Comment: it doesnt even seem to be running the code am i supposed to have some sort of submit button or is the jquery supposed to be posting the fields?

Comment: look into developer console, section 'console' and 'network'. Check for errors

Comment: in the console there is nothing but in network it is running the php file with the status 200 so its okay but the divs that are used have nothing in still

Comment: now add `console.log(response)` right after this line `success: function(response) { ...` and watch the `console` section

Comment: i get nothing on the console still

Comment: ok. place `alert(1)` or `console.log(1)` somewhere within your `setInterval()` function to check if it even starts

Comment: I have updated the origonal question to show the code i have used